# visual-studio-2008 Professional database projects

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, projects

We used some Database Projects in VS2005 Professional.  Am I correct in saying Microsoft removed support in 2008 Professional edition and moved it to Team System instead?

Comment: It's correct to say that the Database project type is only available in VS2008 Team System Database Edition or VS2008 Team Suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked my install of Visual Studio 2008 Pro and 'Database' is available as a new project option (under 'Other Languages').

Comment: I guess you're probably right the Rob.  Unfortunately some cost cutting genius has installed 2008 Std Edition on this machine whereas we had VS 2005 Pro before which would probably be why I don't get that option now!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Database Edition projects (DBPro)? If so, VS Professional doesn't support this for free. You need to be using VS Team Suite or VS Developer Edition.